# Count the number of items in a TikZ foreach statement

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

One sometimes defines macro's for *TikZ* as:

```
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{
    \foreach \x in {#1} {
        %do something
    }
}
```

Thus where the argument given to `\foo` is used in a `\foreach` loop.

Sometimes, one wants to know the number of items in advance, for instance to divide the width of an object among the given items. You can do this using a counter:

```
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{
    \setcounter{tmpA}{0}
    \foreach \x in {#1} {
        \stepcounter{tmpA}
    }
    \foreach \x in {#1} {
        %do something
    }
}
```

Thus using a counter `tmpA` and increment it the first time, and then iterate a second time over the list and use the value of the counter if necessary. One can of course abstract the counting away in a virtual call, but that's not really the problem: one needs to define a counter and there is always a small chance someone else defines a counter with the same name such that they interact.

I was wondering if there are some utility functions defined for *TikZ* foreach items: counting, merging, crossproduct,...

Comment: `\foreach \i [count=\ino] in {...} ...`?

Comment: Didn't know about the `count=` trick, many thanks.

Comment: If you have the current version from e.g. TeX Live 2014, it is on page 913 along with various other options.

Comment: @Andrew: semantically they are "duplicates" although it's in different directions. This question asks what the option is, the other question asks the meaning of that option. No problem to mark this as duplicate...

Comment: @CommuSoft Yes I agree...